# What to do in this situation: several same answers at the same time?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes the following happens: there are the answers given to the same time with the same content ([live example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12885/api-retrieve-record-types-for-contact)). What to do in this situation? I've deleted my own answer as i realized that other was just a few seconds faster.

[image]

Comment: I think that's a good problem to have!

Comment: Gosh, has happened to me more times than I can count! LOL! Agree with you @MikeChale, it's a really good problem to have. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And the power of the community starts to kick in  :-)

Not much to do here.

I see there's a diff of 10 seconds between the other 2 posts.

And your's was even in between them :-)

[image]

[image]

[image]

That said, I guess you all deserve the credit for been online, and active.

You can leave your answer, users might give you credit for it, even that only one can be selected (I would)

Hopefully, we will have this situation on every question.

Comment: Agree with @Saariko, leave your answers as they are or make a edit to give more info. This happens all the time in stackoverflow